# getCurrentUrl does not give me current url

Tags: magento-1.8, url

I want to get current url and check it (if matching) so that I can add 'active' class into my nav bar '< li >' tags. After searching, I found `Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()` could do that but it is not working for me. It gives me `http://mydomain/app/etc/local.xml`

Any reasons why I got that url string?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following:

```
 var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

If it still returns the local.xml, this is a **server** issue. Don't try to go around it, and fix it.

Comment: Can you please let me know what kind of server issue it is?
We are also facing same issue with our project. 
We are using git repository for our project.

Answer (score 0):

**Another way to get Current url :**

```
$urlRequest = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest();
$urlPart = $urlRequest->getServer('ORIG_PATH_INFO');
if(is_null($urlPart))
{
$urlPart = $urlRequest->getServer('PATH_INFO');
}
$urlPart = substr($urlPart, 1 );
echo $currentUrl = $this->getUrl($urlPart);
```

Comment: Hi @Supravat, Thanks for your answer. But it give me http://mydomain/403.shtml no matter which page I am on.

Comment: @GarlicBread, please replace the following code & check  if(!in_array(Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName(), array('cms_index_noRoute', 'cms_index_defaultNoRoute'))) 
{ echo '<br/>'.$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(); }